# Include javascript file that doesn't affect other pages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a orders.js.coffee file that includes some code to disable a checkout button in the orders page. Now the checkout button is show on every page of the website because it is rendered as a partial using ajax on the application layout. So now when i go to the orders page it supposed to be disabled. It does disable but it also disables in every other page. how do i make the orders.js.coffee file to take effect in only the orders page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default Rails includes every file in your `assets/javascripts` directory in every page. That's what the `require_tree .` directive does in `application.js`.

To alter this behaviour you need to:

1. Remove the `require_tree .` line from your `application.js`
2. In the layout that your order pages use, explicitly add `orders.js`:

   `<%= javascript_include_tag "orders" %>`
3. Add `orders.js` to the precompilation step in `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

   `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( orders.js )`

You can find details of a similar but more flexible in this blog article (full disclosure, I wrote it): http://theflyingdeveloper.com/controller-specific-assets-with-rails-4/

Answer (score 0):

If you are *using same layout for each contoller* then to make your orders.js.coffee file specific to orders_controller you can do something like:

```
<% if params[:controller] == "orders" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "orders" %>
<% end %>
```

You will need to `remove the //= require_tree .` from your application.js file and require each file individually.

If you are using **a different layout for your checkout page** then you can simply include

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "order" %>  #add this only for the checkout layout
```

You can also add controller specific js in your app by using

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> #here params[:controller] will be replaced by your controller name and hence only that js will be loaded for that controller.
```

For more information you can refer [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to check what page you are on before disabling the button. So, as was pointed out by @Mandeep, `require tree .` puts everything together into one Javascript file. So all the code is available to every page you render. Consider this:

```
disable_orders_button ->
  $('#some-orders-button-selector').hide() # or whatever you want to do.

page_is_orders ->
  Location.href.match(/orders/) isnt null

$(document).ready ->
  disable_orders_button() if page_is_orders()
```

There are some tweaks you could make like using a specific id just on the orders page so the button would be found only on that page. I.e.,

```
<html>
  <body id="orders">
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <button id="order">Order</button>
  </body>
<html>

# Coffeescript
$('body#orders > button#order').hide()
```

This is air code, but it should illustrate a few techniques you might use.